# Unable to remove data from array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am attempting to remove data from an array that I have added and want to specifically remove this data based on one variable to bring all the data from the array and then remove it.

Getting an error that says:

> bad operand types for binary operator'-'
>   on line `arr[j] = new Studnet(arr{j+i].Getid`.........."

```
private void removeStudent() {

   if(count == 0){
      System.out.println("No Records");
   } else {   
      Scanner intput = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter an ID: ");
      String id = intput.next();
      int res = 0;
      int loc = 0;
      Student[] temp = new Student[10];
      for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

         if(arr[i].getId().equals(id)){

            for(int j = i; i < arr.length - 1; j++) {

                arr[j] = new Student(arr[j+1].getId() - 1, arr[j+1].getFname(), arr[j+1].getLname(), arr[j+1].getAge());
            }
            loc = i;
            res = 1;
      }
  }
  temp = null;
  count--;
  arr = temp;
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Removed Record");
  scanner.nextLine();
  if(res == 1) {

  } else
    System.out.println("No Result");
}   
}
```

This is my code on the separate file that has all the get functions

```
public class Student {

    private String id;
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private int age;
    private int count;

    Student(String id, String fname, String lname, int age, int count) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.age = age;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public double getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Id is a string you cant calculate with it. (Like getId()- 1)

Edit:
This is a really simple example to show you, how it CAN work... but there different ways (maybe better ways) to solve your root problem. (See my first comment)

```
 for(int j = i; i < arr.length - 1; j++){
    int newId = Integer.parseInt(arr[j+1].getId()) -1;
    arr[j] = new Student(Integer.toString(newId), arr[j+1].getFname(), arr[j+1].getLname(), arr[j+1].getAge());
  }
```

Comment: Oh ok thats the issue, so would i need to change the operator or change  from string to int for example?

Comment: You can change it to int, if it is possible for you and your problem should be fixed .... or you can use a "parser" or a "special" getter that returns an converted int. (Maybe exception if the string is not parsable)

Comment: Im unsure of how to add the Integer.parseInt onto the code could you show me where??

Comment: i edit my answer,.... in the topic you say its javascript ... but it is java right? Maybe you should edit this.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to minus 1 on a string. That is why you got the error. 
Do you want to try to get the ID in intger form, and then minus 1 so you can assign the previous ID to that student object?

If yes, try the below in order to convert it to integer and then minus 1:
Integer.parseInt(arr[j+1].getId())-1

Comment: Could you show me exactly where to implement the Integer.parseInt please?